# What are the disadvantages of making methods just functions with a 'this' first parameter?

Tags: functions, methods

In Lua, a function is no different from a method, except that a method has `this` as the first parameter, and calling a method on an object automatically passes the object as the first parameter. In C++, there is [special handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486279/16217248) of functions versus member functions.

The advantage of the first option is simplicity and flexibility, as there is no *'unnecessary'* distinction between methods and functions. But are there any disadvantages?

Comment: What even is the alternate option? In every language methods are just functions

Comment: In Swift, there is a calling convention difference: methods always put `self` in a dedicated register, so the first argument (besides `self`) is in the same place either way. Not sure whether that's worth writing an answer for.

Comment: @mousetail It reads to me like they're asking about Java `void foo()` + `static void bar()` vs Python `def foo(self)` + `def bar()`.

Comment: In python you need `@staticmethod` for static methods

Comment: Lua doesn't actually have instance methods unless you count syntactic sugar - functions that take `this` as a first parameter still require a different syntax `a:b()` instead of `a.b()`

Comment: @RubenVerg `a:b(...)` is just syntactic sugar for `a.b(a, ...)`

Comment: Do you mean for transpiling object-oriented code to a non-OO language (so that `MyClass::MyFunction(int x, int y)` becomes something like `MyClass_MyFunction(MyClass* this, int x, int y)`)?  Or treating these as equivalent *within* one language?

Comment: @user16217248-OnStrike I thought it was for (metaclass of a)`.b(a, ...)`, but anyways my point still stands, methods aren't "like functions but with a `this` parameter" they're functions with some sugar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one advantage of having function/method be fundamentally different is, at the syntax level, making it easy to prove that your code doesn't perform method calls.

When reading C++ code, visually one can instantly tell if a call is going to be to a function or to a method:

```
f(a, b);
a.g(b);
```

This might be useful to C++ programmers, as they sometimes want to know when a call could go through a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), because of the potential cost of pointer indirection.

---

I imagine that the reason it's like this is, back when C++ was made, OOP was still controversial and not well understood, things like [UCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax) or [extension methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method) hadn't been invented, and people just didn't want to confuse this brand new "method" concept (and its weird virtual/override magic) with a regular function.

Today, it just seems like a good idea to have a way to abstract over whether something is a method call or a function call, because they are so similar.

Maybe I'm completely wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

In languages like Java, there are no "free standing" functions. Every function is a method, hence there is no reason to specify explicitly that you are calling a method.

If there are both methods and "free standing" functions like C++ or Python, `this.call()` looks like a useful way to show that the method is being called. However developer that defines and then calls mostly methods, not functions, may anyway prefer to mark explicitly that this is a free-standing function rather than the method call. This can be done by explicitly specifying the namespace: `my_functions::my_function(x)`.